# How to Undo an action without affecting tool setting after a single stroke?

Tags: sculpting, weight-painting

I was reading a lot of documentation concerning this theme, also was searching on google (and here), but have no answers :( The problem is in UNDO operation, for example in Weight Paint mode:

- I Increase the brush radius (for example in weight painting mode or sculpting)
- Then Perform a single stroke
- Now undo
- The brush stroke and the brush radius are undone at the same time! But I wanted to undo only the brush stroke

How to UNDO without affecting tool setting such as brush size, strength, and so on?

Comment: I think it's a problem that some have noticed, you can upvote the request in Right Click Select: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Jtfbbc/

Comment: Thank you! Upvoted!